# python local variable sent to function, modified, but was not passed back to program

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a program for a class, which we were instructed to write a unique program of our own. I decided to make one which determines a user's letter grade based off of their average out of 100.
My problem is, I passed my grade counter to my function, but when I try to return it, it remains its starting value at which I defined it.

```
#4. Increment grade count by 1
Gather_Intel(grade_list, grade_count)
print (grade_list, grade_count)

def Gather_Intel(GL, GC):
    g = 0
    while g >= 0:
        g = int(input("Please input a grade (-1 to quit): "))
        GL.append(g)
        GC = GC + 1
    GL.sort
    GL.remove(-1)
    return GL, GC
```

Is there something I missed that I'm not seeing?

Comment: There is another thing that you didn't see. `GL.sort` doesn't do anything. You have to call the function: `GL.sort()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to re-assign the returned values:

```
grade_list, grade_count = Gather_Intel(grade_list, grade_count)
```

Your function does return those values, but without assigning those returned values to something you are effectively ignoring the results.